# Android AlertDialog: TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, system-alert-window

I have tried out everything I know and can find, but still I cannot get my alert dialog to show as a TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT. It shows on my app when I open it, but it does not pop up if my app is not on front.

I've got:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
d.setTitle("App name");
d.setMessage("Message");
d.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
d.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

AlertDialog dialog = d.create();
dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
d.show();
```

And then I have in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

What am I missing??

The function flow before this alert is following:

1. Broadcast receiver listens for incoming sms messages.
2. Once received, it passes the message to a function in MainActivity using "RunOnUIThread".
3. The message is parsed and the alert dialog is shown. Now why the TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT is not working?? I can see from logcat that the message is parsed ok but still alert dialog is not showing up as system alert. Anyone?

Comment: Where you are using current code in Activity or in Service?

Comment: I'm using it from Activity.

Comment: One thing I'm wondering. OS should never close the app for two reasons: 1. I have bound it to a fore ground service so according to android lifecycle specs it should not get easily closed. 2. For testing purposes there is also an active wake lock. Regardless of these facts I can still see onPause and onStop called!? On the other hand, the app seems to handle incoming messages just fine even though it's on background and "stopped". Weird...

Answer (score 0):

The required permission is only for system apps:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" 
   android:protectionLevel=
   "signature|preinstalled|appop|pre23|development"/>
```